# Dates in a database are incrementally moved backwards by a day when records of a field are updated

Tags: node.js, reactjs, windows, postgresql, azure

The application was created with react for front end and nodejs as backend. The database is PostgreSQL and its hosted on azure. The challenge is anytime a record is updated on the application, the dates on that row are automatically moved back incrementally by one day.

Say for example a know your customer system where an address of a customer is updated and automatically the date of birth of that customer is updated and moved back by a day. I can't seem to figure out the solution.

Comment: Although i am thinking it might likely be with the script that is being ran when the records are updated but i would be glad if I can get more enlightenment if that's the likely problem or not.

Comment: 1) Don't add new information as a comment, update your question with the information. 2) Provide example data showing what is going on. 3) Add the code that is dong the updating.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community will help with your issues, but there are certain expectations on you. Please take a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. 
 Then update your question to include sample data, table definition (ddl scripts), the expected results of that data and what you have tried, all as text - **no images**.

Comment: Please add additional information such as more details and what you have tried?

Comment: Thank you for your response. We were able to resolve it by setting this on the variables.
TZ=UTC